# Coding a hunting phase in Battleship python

Tags: python, computer-science

Hello all I am coding a hunting phase (where the AI does a checker board pattern) in battleship. After this I have to do a targeting phase. But the issue with my hunting phase is that when there are two hits in a row the game just runs through an infinite loop and I am not sure where I went wrong. Here is the computer move code that I have so far:

```
def compMove(game):
  moveLigit = False
pick = True
while (not moveLigit):
  while game.previousTurn == '#'
and pick == True:
  if game.twohits == 'no':
  for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
  if game.userBoard[i][j] == '#':
  c = random.randint(0, 1)
if c == 0:
  x = random.randint(i - 1, i + 1)
y = j
game.twohits = 'yes'
pick = False
else :
  x = i
y = random.randint(j - 1, j + 1)
game.twohits = 'sure'
pick = False
if game.twohits == 'yes':
  for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
  if game.userBoard[i][j] == '#':
  x = random.randint(i - 1, i + 1)
y = j
pick = False
else :
  for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
  if game.userBoard[i][j] == '#':
  x = i
y = random.randint(j - 1, j + 1)
pick = False
pick = False



if game.previousTurn != '#':
  x = random.choice([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]) - 1# Make a checkerboard pattern of random selection
y = random.choice([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]) - 1

beforeDropped = game.makeA_Move(True, x, y)# displaying current boards
game.drawBoards(True)
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
if beforeDropped == "*"
or beforeDropped == "#":
  moveLigit = False
elif beforeDropped == " ":
  print("Sorry computer, " + labels[x] + " " + str(y + 1) + " is a miss.")
game.twohits = 'no'
moveLigit = True

else :
  print("Computer did a Hit at " + labels[x] + " " + str(y + 1))
if game.checkIfSunk(True, beforeDropped):
  print(whatShip(beforeDropped) + " sunk")
game.twohits = 'no'
game.previousTurn = ' '

moveLigit = True


return game.checkWinning(True)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didnt know how to tab correct in stackoverflow apparently but the tabbing for moveLegit needs to be back and it is all properly tabbed into the function in my program i swear

Comment: having one huge function for all of your code is, while tempting when just starting out, a horrible idea - makes it very messy to read and debug.  there's quite a bit that I see in this code that could use some fixing, but without a minimal, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's very difficult.

Comment: Ya my coding definitely is not a refined skill as of yet. Im just confused in general how to create the checkerboard pattern properly without all this buggy crap in here

Comment: "infinite loop" would indicate to me that you are using too many `while` loops - check out `for` loops in more depth.

Comment: Don't use tabs. Use an editor such as Notepad++ configured to use spaces, and convert any tabs to spaces. Indent properly and fix this question. It is unreadable.